# Does WP automatically tag posts into the archive?

Tags: posts, tags, archives

We have about 700 posts on our WP site and some of the older ones (+5 years) seem to get tagged as "Archived", under the tag "tag".

I attached a screenshot of the search result with the same article appearing twice. We don't even have a category named "tag".

This started happening after we switched themes.

Any ideas?

[image: Search results]

Answer (score 1):

What your looking at there is a tag called "how to compliment a women".

The first result is your tag/category page being indexed by google, which is normally a good thing.  The word Archive is being added via your theme but it just means its a category/tag page that will display a list of posts.  Again, this is most likely a good thing.

The second result is a page with the slug/url "how to compliment a women" that is also tagged "how to compliment a women".

You should be able to `Admin > Posts > Tags` to view a full list of your tags.